# TensorFlow - Equivalent of model(x) for prediction in TensorFlowJS

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite, tensorflow.js

I trained a model using tf==2.5.0.

Advised to use model(x) instead of model.predict(x) speeds up the inference time. As I understand, model.predict(x) is used for predicting the tensors in batches. For example, model.predict(x) takes 1 second, whereas model(x) takes .02 seconds for executing a single image for detection. When I convert tf model to tfjs, the prediction takes nearly 1 second.

Checking TFJS API, it has only two functionalities for prediction namely

1. predict (x, args?)
2. predictOnBatch (x)

There is no luck, both consume same amount of time (1 second on average).

On the other hand, when the same model is converted to tflite,  there is no reduction in time.

Environment:
Python3.7
Tensorflow: 2.5.0

Any suggestion is appreciated.